# Unable to use dollar sign ($) in java replace method. It is throwing a runtime exception

Tags: java, regex, runtime-error, dollar-sign

I am having my replace method using regex as below,

```
String str1="dog0123456yrhh900man";
String replacedStr=str1.replaceAll("(man|dog)|[^0-9]","$1");
```

Output: `dog0123456900man`

This works fine in normal main method.

but when I include this same logic in my application code which is running in jboss server and environment as linux i am getting runtime error because of this dollar sign.

I tried below also. Its is affecting the expected output

```
replacedStr=str1.replaceAll("(man|dog)|[^0-9]","\\$1");
replacedStr=str1.replaceAll("(man|dog)|[^0-9]","\\\\$1");
replacedStr=str1.replaceAll("(man|dog)|[^0-9]","\\\\\\$1");
```

excpectedoutput: `dog0123456900man`

actual output: `dog0123456$1$1$1$1900man`

i also tried `Matcher.quoteReplacement()`

`replacedStr=str1.replaceAll("(man|dog)|[^0-9]",Matcher.quoteReplacement("$1"));` It is not working.

Kindly help me with suggestion

Comment: This works fine on ideone ([demo](http://ideone.com/klkKi4)).

Comment: @Vinoth what version of Java is jboss running on? Also can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: @assylias jboss version 5 and java version 1.5 above

Comment: @Vinoth Have you tested in a main with the same version of JRE (to make sure it's not a bug in that specific version of java)?

Comment: *"getting runtime error"* What error?

Answer (score 0):

If your testing on windows but your production environment is linux then I had a similar issue with an application i'm working on(albeit the other way round). The problem seems to be related either to font differences or character encoding differences between the two OS's. It could be worthwhile installing a compatible font pack on the linux machine. If that doesnt work you'll have to play about with character encoding in your application to find: either the character equivalent, or change the encoding the string in question to a form that works on your production environment.